# Importer truncates nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, import, xls, truncate

I have table in SQL Server and I want to import data from `xls`. One of the columns in my table is `nvarchar(max)`. When I paste data using "Edit" everything is ok. But when I use "Task->Import Data" it truncates this column to 255. The length of this column in the source file is no more than 800. In column mapping I see that size of this column is "max". What can I change to import this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

There is a limitation while importing data from Excel, a Column can contain max of 255 character. if you have more than 255 character it will truncate the rest. I would suggest you to use .csv instead of .xls